# "prototype does not match any class" error when separating into .h and .cpp files

Tags: c++, c++11

Writing a program for a game of "Mastermind". In one of my classes, code, I have seperated it into .h and .cpp files and I'm not sure why my cpp file keeps giving me this error when compiling: Error: prototype for 'int code :: getVector()' does not match any class in 'code'

To my knowledge I have the correct header for getVector() in my code.h file:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef CODE_H
#define CODE_H

using namespace std;

class code      //strores code vector and checks for correct and incorrect numbers
{
private:

    vector<int> codeVector {0,0,0,0};       //vector storing code (guess and secret code depending on object)

public:

    vector<int> getVector();        //retrievs private codeVector

    void setCodeVectorToGuess(vector<int> guess);   //sets private codeVector to vector passed in

    void setCodeVectorToSecretCode();   //uses rand function to set random secret code vector

    int checkCorrect(code guessObject);     //uses for loop to check what values are correct number correct location by checking equivalence at each vector index

    int checkIncorrect(code guessObject);   //checks numbers between the two vectors using two for loops which each replace values in the vectors with non-equivalent out-of-range numbers

};

#endif // CODE_H
```

and the right syntax in my .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>

#include "code.h"

using namespace std;



//code :: codeVector = {0,0,0,0};

code :: getVector()     //retrieves private codeVector
{
    return codeVector;
}

code :: setCodeVectorToGuess(vector<int> guess) //sets private codeVector to vector passed in
{
    codeVector = guess;
}

code :: setCodeVectorToSecretCode() //uses rand function to set random secret code vector
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    codeVector = {rand() % 5 + 1, rand() % 5 + 1, rand() % 5 + 1, rand() % 5 + 1};
}

code :: checkCorrect(code guessObject)      //uses simple for loop to check what values are correct number correct location
{
    int correctPlaceCorrectNum = 0;

    vector<int> guessVector;
    guessVector = guessObject.getVector();

    for (int o=0; o<codeVector.size(); o++)
    {
        if (codeVector[o] == guessVector[o])
        {
            correctPlaceCorrectNum ++;
        }
    }

    return correctPlaceCorrectNum;
}

code :: checkIncorrect(code guessObject)    //checks numbers between the two vectors using two for loops which each replace values in the vectors with non-equivalent out-of-range numbers
{
    int incorrectPlaceCorrectNum = 0;
    int counter(0), counter2(0);

    int array1[8] = {6,7,8,9};          //two arrays used for the elimination of vector values by substitution of non-equivalent values
    int array2[8] = {10,11,12,13};      //

    vector<int> secretCodeVector {0,0,0,0};     //copy of secret code vector
    secretCodeVector = getVector();

    vector<int> guessVector {0,0,0,0};          //copy of guess vector
    guessVector = guessObject.getVector();

    for (int u=0; u<secretCodeVector.size(); u++)       //checks and replaces all correct number correct location values in secret code vector
    {
        if (secretCodeVector[u] == guessVector[u])
        {

            secretCodeVector[u] = array1[counter];

            counter++;

        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<secretCodeVector.size(); i++)       //checks and replaces all correct number incorrect location values in both vectors
    {

        for (int l=0; l<secretCodeVector.size(); l++)           //checks each digit of secret code with all digits of guess code
        {
            if (secretCodeVector[i] == guessVector[l])  
            {
                secretCodeVector[i] = array1[counter];
                guessVector[l] = array2[counter2];


                incorrectPlaceCorrectNum++;

                counter++;
                counter2++;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    return incorrectPlaceCorrectNum;

}
```

Comment: You need to provide return types for the function in the cpp file.

Comment: I suspect that you have disabled compiler warnings.  Turn them back on, so the compiler can tell you it is **guessing** that your return type is `int` everywhere you have omitted it.

Comment: Appears you are trying to write a getter method (for the vector).  see http://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html.  There are plenty of articles both ways on this.   I do not use getters or setters, and recommend against them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the declarations of your functions in the .h file and the definitions in the .cpp file do not match: In the .h file you declare:

```
vector<int> code::getVector()
```

and in the .cpp file:

```
code::getVector()
```

The problem is that they don´t match, but they have to match. Write

```
vector<int> code::getVector()
{
    // code here 
}
```

The same is valid for all the other definitions.

In ancient times giving no return type meant that the return type is int, which explains the error message you observe. But this is banned for a long time and should have given a warning.

Comment: Could someone explain to me, why this answer gets downvoted? Pls?

Comment: I don't downvote, but, I would say that you answer contains the right thing to do but at the same time contains a lot of "not totaly correct" information. Do you know the KISS? If it was applied you would have avoided the downvotes.

Comment: @StefanoBuora better now?

Comment: The votes talk for me ;)